# Call jQuery function from frame

Tags: jquery

I have a frameset page that includes header and footer

```
<script>
$(function() {      
    ///////////////////
    // Initialize Popup
    ///////////////////
    $("#openPopup").bind("singletap", function() {
      var $this = jQuery(this),description = $this.data('description'),title = $this.data('title');
      //alert(description);
      $.UIPopup({
        id: "warning",
        title: title, 
        message: "<iframe src="+description +" width='320' height='320' frameborder='0' style='border:0' allowfullscreen marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'>Loading...</iframe></iframe>",
        cancelButton:'إغلاق', 
        //continueButton: 'Stay', 
        callback: function() {
          var popupMessageTarget = document.querySelector('#popupMessageTarget');
          popupMessageTarget.textContent = '';
          popupMessageTarget.className = "";
          popupMessageTarget.className = "animatePopupMessage";
        }
      });
    });             
});
</script>

<frameset rows="*,63" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" border="0">
<frame name="main" src="clinics_header.html">
<frame name="footer" scrolling="no" src="clinics_footer.html"     noresize="noresize"  target="_parent">
<noframes>
<body>

</body>
</noframes>
</frameset>
```

The footer page has 2 buttons:

```
<div class="toolbar current">
<button onclick="go_index()">Home</button>
<button id="openPopup" data-description="add" > Add </button>
</div>
```

I want to call the jQuery function in the parent page from the button in the footer page.

Comment: why is anyone still using frames in 2016? They are deprecated and a thing of the 1990's

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to this question is to move away from using HTML frames, as it is [deprecated from current web standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame).

However, if that's not an option, you can use the [window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) to call a jQuery method on an element in the topmost page:

```
$('#yourElement', window.top).someFunction();
```

Comment: assumes that jQuery is available in the frame, if not call a function in `top`

Comment: @charlietfl I suppose you're right. Daina, does the frame include jQuery?

Comment: @charlietfl I added jquery.js to the frame header.

Comment: $('#yourElement', window.top).someFunction(); Would that work!! as the fucntion does not have a name!!

Comment: @DainaHodges What do you mean by the function does not have a name? What jQuery function are you trying to call?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister the fucntion in the second line of my post

Comment: @DainaHodges I would give the function a name, then you could access the function from within the frame like this: `window.top.myFunction`